# getComponent("fieldName").setValue() Not Working

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

**Scenario:** I had a requirement for my XPage application like, there were 3 options for a check box group field. And there were 3 different tables contains contains more than 10 fields(binded with datasource) of each table. Whatever the options selected from the checkbox, the corresponding table should be displayed(There is no default value for checkbox group and all the 3 tables were hidden is=nitially). Because its a checkbox, all options can be checked, and if any option is unchecked then the corresponding table should be hidden and the values entered in those fields within the table should be cleared. This is the requirement and its so simple and  will take very little time to finish it out. But the problem arises here.

**Problem:** In the onClick() event of the checkbox I have written SSJS code to clear the value of set of fields in that particular table whose option is unchecked. But its not happening.

```
var ckbxValue = getComponent("checkBox").getValue();
if(!@Contains(ckbxValue,"1stOption"))
{
    array_1 = new Array("txtFld_1","txtFld_2","txtFld_3","txtFld_4","txtFld_5","txtFld_etc");
    for(d=0;d<array_1.length;d++)
    {
        //currentDocument.setValue(array_1[d],"");
        getComponent(array_1[d]).setValue("");
    }
}
```

When I uncheck the 1st option, 1st table will hide and this will execute and will clear the field values. But the values were not cleared. But the same code works for computed text(which is not binded) and also works for those fields when the table is visible. I can't understand why this is not happening.

I have done an another workaround and fulfilled the requirement for time being. I want to know what's happening in that time.

What I found was, Initially there was a hidden binded field, I am setting the value as "AAA" by clicking in a button. Now I display the button is some condition with full update and the field will display the value "AAA". Now the field is visible and I am setting the value as "BBB" by clicking an another button. Now it will show the value as "BBB". I am hiding it now and setting the value as "CCC" and again making the field visible. Now I need to see the value "CCC", but I am seeing "BBB". How its happening?

Can anyone make me understand why its happening like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Don't go after the component. The best approach is to bind a component to a scoped variable and read that variable. Especially with checkboxes that saves you a lot of trouble.

Consider a UI element a visualization, not data. Business logic always acts on data, not on its visual representation.

Give it a shot.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd statement is true. But the problem for me is with the Editbox UI component. Its behaving differently when we toggle its visibility. Can you please clarify a bit more.

Comment: The trouble with 'visibility' is that it's actually whether the component is 'rendered' or not, rather than whether it is visible. So, when it computes visibility/rendered as false, that element is NOT AVAILABLE, not just hidden. It's a poorly labelled property that becomes more obvious in the source code than on the design tab. It might be useful to include the code for the checkbox to further troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Stephan is absolutely correct: components exist for *users* to interact with, data sources are for *code* to interact with. Never use `getComponent("id").setValue("value")`... instead, use `dataSource.setValue("property", "value")` or `someScope.put("property","value")`. This maps to whatever the value binding of the component is, e.g. `<xp:text value="#{dataSource.property}" />`. If a component is not bound to data, but you need to change its value programmatically, bind it to data, and update your code to talk to that data... the component will pick up the new value automatically.